# How to generate an array of week numbers in node js using moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I've use case in which I need to generate an array of last 6 week numbers starting from current week number. Now this is 5th week of 2020. I have to create an array like,

`[52,1,2,3,4,5]`

This is a dynamic array which has to be generated using moment.js week() method. I know how to get current week number using moment but don't know how to create this kind of an array.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far. Anyway check the momentjs docs to see if it takes a parameter which it probably does. Try iterating and add the values to your array. Or you just get the current week and iterate 6 times while decrementing the week number and adding it to your array. Watch out for the use of the modulo operator to not hit negative week numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the 5th week of 2020 ;-). A simple for loop will do the job:

```
const dates = []
for (let i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
   dates.unshift(moment().add(-i, 'weeks').week())
}
console.log(dates);
```